# In what ways can I access a variable defined in a JSR223 Sampler from inside a child JSR223 PostProcessor?

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223

In JMeter I have a JSR223 Sampler in which I have some variable with a timestamp value which changes on each sampler iteration.
Directly underneath the JSR223 Sampler, I have a JSR223 PostProcessor. In this PostProcessor, I want to get the variable from the parent JSR223 Sampler, do some processing on it (subtract some other timestamp value) and use the result into `prev.elapsedTime(processedTimestampValue)` to amend the time of the previous JSR223 Sampler.

In what ways can I achieve this?

I think that I can use `vars.put('variableValue')` in the JSR223 Sampler to make the variable value available to JMeter and then use `vars.get('variableValue')` in JSR223 PostProcessor to make use of this value, but I was wondering if there is another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Directly underneath` means that the JSR223 PostProcessor will be applied to all [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) in its [scope](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide), if you want to amend time of a single Sampler - make the JSR223 PostProcessor **a child** of this Sampler

[image]

`I was wondering if there is another way` - there is, you can use "Parameters" section as well:

[image]

More information: [JSR223 Sampler Documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)